# Access :Using VBA code on form controls separately(for each record)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

ive attached a picture of my form, what's currently happening is that when i select the right combo_box value it changes the values in the left combo box accordingly, this is what i want, however this changes the values for ALL left combo_boxes in all records, i want it to only change for the specific record i'm currently editing.

[image]

this is the code for updating the left combo_box values :

```
Private Sub ride_combo_AfterUpdate()

Me.maint_combo.Requery


End Sub
```

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the row source for your second combo is referencing (and dependent on) the values in the first combo.

The native grid-type forms in MS Access such as the Continuous Form and the Datasheet form, do not allow you to manipulate controls on a row-by-row basis. In other words, what you want to do isn't possible. Yes, you can manipulate the value of controls for the record you're on, but if you want to modify and other property (such as row source, background color, etc) all rows will be affected.

The only way to get independent, row-by-row behavior in MS Access is to use an ActiveX grid control such as the iGrid from 10tec. Or the Microsoft List View control.